# select() function for simultaneously I/O

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, select, io

I am trying to implement a multi-threading server which can handle with simultaneously read/write from client.
The server method:

The client connects to the server, when each message starts with the name of the user they want to send the message to, followed by '|'. It looks something like that: "USER_NAME|DATA".

After receiving the data, the server knows by a dictionary of {socket:username} where to send the data. Everything works great, except the fact that the client can't handle with simultaneously reading and writing. I searched for a method to handle that and i found the select() function, but with a lack of examples- i couldn't integrate that function in my code.

therefore I have 2 questions:

1. Is the select() function should be on the server side? will it be more efficient?
2. Is someone can demonstrate with a simple example how the select() method should look in the client side?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though select() will work, you have to use threads if you want to do other things while the system is blocked on the select.

Have a look at glib's GIO library. There you can connect callbacks to the actions you want to monitor or act on, for example the 'connect's from clients.

Just open a socket, and use its file descriptor to hang a gio.add_watch on. Here's [a mini-tutorial](http://localhost/soft/howto/gtk/giochannel.en.php) on using giochannels.

Comment: **Thank you very much!**  i'll take a look. Anyway- i do have threads, which work without any problems, I just wanted to add the select() :)

Comment: Programming would be boring if everyone wrote code the same way :-) Though I am using threads in some programs, I feel more comfortable with event-driven functions.